# Binned Histogram with overlay of empirical and/or normal distribution

Tags: r, ggplot2, frequency-distribution

I am trying to look at the frequency distribution of a certain variable. Due to the large amount of data, I have created bins for a range of values and I'm plotting the count of each bin. I want to be able to overlay lines which will represent both the empirical distribution seen by my data, and what a theoretically normal distribution would look like. I can accomplish this without pre-binning my data or using ggplot2 by doing something such as this:

```
df <- ggplot2::diamonds
hist(df$price,freq = FALSE)
lines(density(df$price),lwd=3,col="blue")
```

or with ggplot2 as such:

```
mean_price <- mean(df$price)
sd_price <- sd(df$price)

ggplot(df, aes(x = price)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), 
                 bins = 40,  colour = "black", fill = "white") +
  geom_line(aes(y = ..density.., color = 'Empirical'), stat = 'density') +     
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, aes(color = 'Normal'),
                args = list(mean = mean_price, sd = sd_price)) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = "Colors", values = c("red", "blue"))
```

but I cannot figure out how to overlay similar lines on my pre-binned data:

```
breaks <- seq(from=min(df$price),to=max(df$price),length.out=11)
price_freq <- cut(df$price,breaks = breaks,right = TRUE,include.lowest = TRUE)
ggplot(data = df,mapping = aes(x=price_freq)) +
  stat_count() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 270)) 
  # + geom_line(aes(y = ..density.., color = 'Empirical'), stat = 'density') +     
  # stat_function(fun = dnorm, aes(color = 'Normal'),
  #               args = list(mean = mean_price, sd = sd_price)) +
  # scale_colour_manual(name = "Colors", values = c("red", "blue"))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: also, this thread links to plenty of other threads dealing with that same problem

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `cut` gives you a factor/character for your x-axis.  You need a numeric x-axis to add the other layers.  A first step might be to try the following.  I added a small fudge to get the last bin to work out.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- ggplot2::diamonds

mean_price <- mean(df$price)
sd_price <- sd(df$price)

num_bins <- 40
breaks <- seq(from=min(df$price),to=max(df$price)+1e-10,length.out=num_bins+1)
midpoints <- (breaks[1:num_bins] + breaks[2:(num_bins+1)])/2

precomputed <- df %>% 
    mutate(bin_left = breaks[findInterval(price, breaks)],
           bin_mid = midpoints[findInterval(price, breaks)]) %>%
    count(bin_mid) 

precomputed %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = bin_mid, weight = n)) +
    geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), bins = num_bins, boundary = breaks[1], colour = "black", fill = "white") +
    geom_line(aes(y = ..density.., color = 'Empirical'), stat = 'density') +
    stat_function(fun = dnorm, aes(color = 'Normal'),
                  args = list(mean = mean_price, sd = sd_price)) +
    scale_colour_manual(name = "Colors", values = c("red", "blue"))
```

But you will notice that the red Empirical curve is quite different from your `ggplot2` example.  The reason is that here it is being computed using the summary data which moves all x-values to the bin midpoint.  You will need to pre-compute this empirical curve, or drop it and rely on the histogram to represent this data.

Sorry for the partial answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the PearsonDS package ( I am guessing you are not using rnorm for a reason).  The easiest approach may be to generate a vector of data that meets your requirements and map that vector using geom_line.

```
library("PearsonDS")
df <- rpearson(5000,moments=c(mean=10,variance=2,skewness=0,kurtosis=3))
```